Fluent UI Web Components theming
I'm implementing web application with Microsoft Fluent UI Web Components. I'm trying to get control over colors on the Fluent Components. I saw there are "Design Tokens" what I can manipulate, but this didn't give me full control over the colors. For Example if I want to modify the background color of a "fluent-card" I can't. If someone have experience with Fluent UI Web Components and styling them, should be happy to give me any advices.
Tried with some of the "Design Tokens" but this works only for some of the colors(button color, shadow color and etc.) but not directly over "fluent-card" background color.
Code:
import { allComponents, SwatchRGB, accentBaseColor, neutralBaseColor, neutralLayer4, fillColor, provideFluentDesignSystem } from '../../node_modules/@fluentui/web-components/dist/web-components.js';

neutralBaseColor.setValueFor(document.body, SwatchRGB.from(parseColorHexRGB('#ee4060')));
accentBaseColor.setValueFor(document.body, SwatchRGB.from(parseColorHexRGB('#ee4060')));

